# monetdblite performance trace

Tags: performance, benchmarking, trace, monetdblite

MonetDBLite has no trace capabilities. The Release version compiled with Visual Studio is faster than the one compiled with MinGW64, optimizations used on both (/O2). But even so, the fastest version seems to be 3-4 times slower than the time reported in mclient for the same imported data, query and disk storage (same ssd), being benchmarked at ~6sec for dll, vs 1.8sec for monetdb server. I expected the lite version to have comparable time (the article describes the lite library as being mostly faster than monetdb itself). MonetDBLite is the one downloaded in October 2018, while MonetDB server is Aug 2018.SP2 version.

In the absence of any trace capability (sys.tracelog() is a dummy function), is it any way I can debug this situation?

Comment: Use a standard profiler I'd say.

Comment: A standard profiler did not help much. the dll uses more memory, has more disk (writing) activity, and executes slower than the server when data, disk-storage and query are identical. Is the dll configured to store results on disk even if fetching was not requested? (that would explain, I guess)